# Jekyll - Code block background colours not consistent

Tags: css, sass, jekyll, minima

I have a Jekyll website that I'm running locally with `bundle exec jekyll serve`, using the `Minima` default theme.

When I use a code block, the background colour of the box and the background colour of the text in the box is different, resulting in an ugly presentation:

````
```r
filter(grepl("A", Source)) %>%
group_by(Source) %>%
summarise(Amount = sum(Amount)) %>%
mutate(Percentage = Amount / sum(Amount) * 100)
```
````

[image]

This issue occurs for most languages I define at the start of the code block and when no language is defined (e.g. ```` ```r ````, ```` ```python ```` ```` ``` ````), but not funnily not for ```` ```shell-script ````.

The relevant `_sass/minima/_base.scss` section (I think) looks like this:

```
/**
 * Blockquotes
 */
blockquote {
  color: $grey-color;
  border-left: 4px solid $grey-color-light;
  padding-left: $spacing-unit / 2;
  @include relative-font-size(1.125);
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-style: italic;

  > :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}



/**
 * Code formatting
 */
pre,
code {
  @include relative-font-size(0.9375);
  border: 1px solid $grey-color-light;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

code {
  padding: 1px 5px;
}

pre {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  overflow-x: auto;

  > code {
    border: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

**How do I make the entire code block use the grey colour currently only being used for the text background?**

*edit*: After disabling the rouge syntax highlighter the code blocks appear correctly, along with the syntax highlighting.

*edit*: This issue also occurs when the website is built with github pages

Comment: Take a look at the generated HTML. What do you see? FWIW, I personally prefer something like `{% highlight somelanguage %}` and never had that problem.

Comment: It loos like "shell-script" is appearing correctly: <pre><code class="language-shell-script">CODE
</code></pre> but "r" is putting each word in its own <span> tag: <span class="n">CODE</span>

Comment: It looks like it's something to do with the rouge syntax highlighter, when I disable it, the code blocks are displayed correctly, but I have no syntax highlighting

Comment: Yes, the highlighter adds all these spans. Each of them can have a different text colour, font, etc., depending on its class You should define those in the CSS files for your HTML. No hightlighter, no syntax highlighting. I prefer RedCloth over Rouge, by the way. It also knows Delphi, which is my main language.